# POST-request won't trigger from angular

Tags: asp.net, angular, rest, post, ionic-framework

I've made a database that keeps game data. Testing has shown that adding a "team" to a "game" does work. However, my angular application won't trigger the database.

I made sure that the database function worked with swagger in ASP.net

```
export class AlloutProvider {
    url: string;
    constructor(private _http: HttpClient) {
        this.url = "http://localhost:33324/api/v1"
    };

    postTeam(team: Team) {
        console.log(this.url + "game/team")
        console.log(JSON.stringify(team))
        return this._http.post(this.url + "game/team", JSON.stringify(team));
    }
}
```

[image: Verification of the URL]

Comment: missing `subsription` like: `postTeam().subscribe()`?

Comment: Is there a missing slash? `this.url = "http://localhost:33324/api/v1"` and `this.url + "game/team"` would give you: `http://localhost:33324/api/v1game/team`, missing the slash between the v1 and the game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
 this._http.post(this.url + "game/team", JSON.stringify(team));
```

for

```
this._http.post(this.url + "/game/team", JSON.stringify(team));
```

Comment: It is great that you provided an answer in code, but since it is a very subtle change, you could explain what is changed, and why?

Comment: It does indeed seem like the *post* method adds a slash by itself.